# Pandas convert dataframe to array of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have manipulated some data using pandas and now I want to carry out a batch save back to the database. This requires me to convert the dataframe into an array of tuples, with each tuple corresponding to a "row" of the dataframe.

My DataFrame looks something like:

```
In [182]: data_set
Out[182]: 
  index data_date   data_1  data_2
0  14303 2012-02-17  24.75   25.03 
1  12009 2012-02-16  25.00   25.07 
2  11830 2012-02-15  24.99   25.15 
3  6274  2012-02-14  24.68   25.05 
4  2302  2012-02-13  24.62   24.77 
5  14085 2012-02-10  24.38   24.61
```

I want to convert it to an array of tuples like:

```
[(datetime.date(2012,2,17),24.75,25.03),
(datetime.date(2012,2,16),25.00,25.07),
...etc. ]
```

Any suggestion on how I can efficiently do this?

Comment: For those coming to this answer in 2017+, there is a [new idiomatic solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34551914/3707607). You can just use `list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))`

Comment: The two things I'm looking for when I come to this question: A list of tuples - `df.to_records(index=False)` and a list of dicts: `df.to_dict('records')`

Comment: @MartinThoma both to_records and to_dict('records') screw my data-types. Known bug but makes this solutions worthless...

Answer (score 357, accepted):

```
list(data_set.itertuples(index=False))
```

As of 17.1, the above will return a [list of namedtuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html).

If you want a list of ordinary tuples, pass `name=None` as an argument:

```
list(data_set.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO (now that a dedicated feature exists). BTW, if you want normal `tuple`s in your `zip` iterator (instead of `namedtuple`s), then call: `data_set.itertuples(index=False, name=None)`

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't. [`itertuples` is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues). Avoid if possible. [For loops (as shown the the accepted answer) is usually faster in these cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

Comment: @coldspeed The lesson I got from the linked question is that itertuples is slow because converting to tuples is usually slower than vectorized/cython operations. Given that the question is asking to convert to tuples, is there any reason that we'd think that the accepted answer is faster? The quick test I did indicates that the itertuples version is faster.

Comment: I posted my speed test results in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54952229/3358599)

Comment: @cs95 _[itertuples is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues)._ The performance of `.iterrows()` is notoriously bad compared to that of `.itertuples()` though. In some simple benchmarks I ran the former was around 1000 times slower than the latter, they can hardly be compared.

Comment: @cs95 Would it not be better to state: "Avoid when optimizing"?

Comment: @johnDanger it's similar to the concept of eval() and globals() in python. Everyone knows they exist. Everyone also knows you typically shouldn't use these functions because it's considered bad form. The principle here is similar, there are very few cases to use the iter* family in pandas, this is arguably one of them. I'd still use a different method (like a list comp or map) but that's me.

Comment: This did not work for me when I use the df with pymssql, so I use the `data = [tuple(r) for r in df.to_numpy()]` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285244/convert-a-dataframe-to-list-of-tuples) worked for me.

Answer (score 262):

How about:

```
subset = data_set[['data_date', 'data_1', 'data_2']]
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in subset.to_numpy()]
```

for pandas < 0.24 use

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
```

Comment: Please see @ksindi's answer below for using `.itertuples`, which will be more efficient than getting the values as an array and t urning them into a tuple.

Comment: slightly cleaner is:  tuples=map(tuple,subset.values)

Comment: This can cast values to a different type though, right?

Answer (score 53):

**Motivation**
Many data sets are large enough that we need to concern ourselves with speed/efficiency.  So I offer this solution in that spirit.  It happens to also be succinct.

For the sake of comparison, let's drop the `index` column

```
df = data_set.drop('index', 1)
```

**Solution**
I'll propose the use of `zip` and `map`

```
list(zip(*map(df.get, df)))

[('2012-02-17', 24.75, 25.03),
 ('2012-02-16', 25.0, 25.07),
 ('2012-02-15', 24.99, 25.15),
 ('2012-02-14', 24.68, 25.05),
 ('2012-02-13', 24.62, 24.77),
 ('2012-02-10', 24.38, 24.61)]
```

It happens to also be flexible if we wanted to deal with a specific subset of columns.  We'll assume the columns we've already displayed are the subset we want.

```
list(zip(*map(df.get, ['data_date', 'data_1', 'data_2'])))

[('2012-02-17', 24.75, 25.03),
 ('2012-02-16', 25.0, 25.07),
 ('2012-02-15', 24.99, 25.15),
 ('2012-02-14', 24.68, 25.05),
 ('2012-02-13', 24.62, 24.77),
 ('2012-02-10', 24.38, 24.61)]
```

---

#### What is Quicker?

Turn's out `records` is quickest followed by asymptotically converging `zipmap` and `iter_tuples`

I'll use a library [`simple_benchmarks`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/simple_benchmark) that I got from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56398618/2336654)

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
b = BenchmarkBuilder()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def tuple_comp(df): return [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
def iter_namedtuples(df): return list(df.itertuples(index=False))
def iter_tuples(df): return list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
def records(df): return df.to_records(index=False).tolist()
def zipmap(df): return list(zip(*map(df.get, df)))

funcs = [tuple_comp, iter_namedtuples, iter_tuples, records, zipmap]
for func in funcs:
    b.add_function()(func)

def creator(n):
    return pd.DataFrame({"A": random.randint(n, size=n), "B": random.randint(n, size=n)})

@b.add_arguments('Rows in DataFrame')
def argument_provider():
    for n in (10 ** (np.arange(4, 11) / 2)).astype(int):
        yield n, creator(n)

r = b.run()
```

Check the results

```
r.to_pandas_dataframe().pipe(lambda d: d.div(d.min(1), 0))

        tuple_comp  iter_namedtuples  iter_tuples   records    zipmap
100       2.905662          6.626308     3.450741  1.469471  1.000000
316       4.612692          4.814433     2.375874  1.096352  1.000000
1000      6.513121          4.106426     1.958293  1.000000  1.316303
3162      8.446138          4.082161     1.808339  1.000000  1.533605
10000     8.424483          3.621461     1.651831  1.000000  1.558592
31622     7.813803          3.386592     1.586483  1.000000  1.515478
100000    7.050572          3.162426     1.499977  1.000000  1.480131
```

---

```
r.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 50):

A generic way:

```
[tuple(x) for x in data_set.to_records(index=False)]
```

Comment: Isn't `data_set.to_records(index=False).tolist()` better?

Comment: @AmirShabani cast to List is preferred over this one to avoid losing the data type and format. For eg. when a column is of type pandas DateTime the date format won't be kept as it is.

Answer (score 17):

The most efficient and easy way:

```
list(data_set.to_records())
```

You can filter the columns you need before this call.

Comment: I think 'index=False' should be given as an argument to to_records(). Thus, list(data_set.to_records(index=False))

Comment: This is not what the OP asked: the result of `to_records` is not a tuple but rather a numpy record array. When you need an actual `tuple` - e.g. because you need to hash it - this solution won't cut it.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a vectorized approach (assuming the dataframe, `data_set` to be defined as `df` instead) that returns a `list` of `tuples` as shown:

```
>>> df.set_index(['data_date'])[['data_1', 'data_2']].to_records().tolist()
```

produces:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 17, 0, 0), 24.75, 25.03),
 (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 16, 0, 0), 25.0, 25.07),
 (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 15, 0, 0), 24.99, 25.15),
 (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 14, 0, 0), 24.68, 25.05),
 (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 13, 0, 0), 24.62, 24.77),
 (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 10, 0, 0), 24.38, 24.61)]
```

The idea of setting datetime column as the index axis is to aid in the conversion of the `Timestamp` value to it's corresponding `datetime.datetime` format equivalent by making use of the `convert_datetime64` argument in [`DF.to_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) which does so for a `DateTimeIndex` dataframe.

This returns a `recarray` which could be then made to return a `list` using `.tolist`

---

More generalized solution depending on the use case would be:

```
df.to_records().tolist()                              # Supply index=False to exclude index
```

Answer (score 14):

Changing the data frames list into a list of tuples.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
print(df)
OUTPUT
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6

records = df.to_records(index=False)
result = list(records)
print(result)
OUTPUT
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 12):

This answer doesn't add any answers that aren't already discussed, but here are some speed results. I think this should resolve questions that came up in the comments. All of these look like they are *O(n)*, based on these three values.

**TL;DR**: `tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))` and `tuples = list(zip(*[df[c].values.tolist() for c in df]))` are tied for the fastest.

I did a quick speed test on results for three suggestions here:

1. The zip answer from @pirsquared: `tuples = list(zip(*[df[c].values.tolist() for c in df]))`
2. The accepted answer from @wes-mckinney: `tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]`
3. The itertuples answer from @ksindi with the `name=None` suggestion from @Axel: `tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))`

```
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd


def create_random_df(n):
    return pd.DataFrame({"A": random.randint(n, size=n), "B": random.randint(n, size=n)})
```

Small size:

```
df = create_random_df(10000)
%timeit tuples = list(zip(*[df[c].values.tolist() for c in df]))
%timeit tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
%timeit tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Gives:

```
1.66 ms ± 200 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
15.5 ms ± 1.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.74 ms ± 75.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Larger:

```
df = create_random_df(1000000)
%timeit tuples = list(zip(*[df[c].values.tolist() for c in df]))
%timeit tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
%timeit tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Gives:

```
202 ms ± 5.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
1.52 s ± 98.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
209 ms ± 11.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As much patience as I have:

```
df = create_random_df(10000000)
%timeit tuples = list(zip(*[df[c].values.tolist() for c in df]))
%timeit tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
%timeit tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Gives:

```
1.78 s ± 118 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
15.4 s ± 222 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.68 s ± 96.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The zip version and the itertuples version are within the confidence intervals each other. I suspect that they are doing the same thing under the hood.

These speed tests are probably irrelevant though. Pushing the limits of my computer's memory doesn't take a huge amount of time, and you *really* shouldn't be doing this on a large data set. Working with those tuples after doing this will end up being really inefficient. It's unlikely to be a major bottleneck in your code, so just stick with the version you think is most readable.

Comment: I updated my stale post.  I'd been using `[*zip(*map(df.get, df))]` for sometime now.  Anyway, thought you'd find it interesting.

Comment: @piRSquared Oooh. I like the pretty plot. I guess that looks about like it's *O(n)*.

Answer (score 4):

```
#try this one:

tuples = list(zip(data_set["data_date"], data_set["data_1"],data_set["data_2"]))
print (tuples)
```

Answer (score 3):

More pythonic way:

```
df = data_set[['data_date', 'data_1', 'data_2']]
map(tuple,df.values)
```

Comment: _More pythonic way:_ The exact opposite, actually. `map()` is notoriously unpythonic.

Answer (score 2):

To Convert Dataframe Column into Arrays of Tuple without Index:

```
import pandas as pd
my_converted_array_tuples = pd.Dataframe(mydf['my_column_name']).to_records(index=False)
```

Note: If you need Index remove index line