# Pandas dataframe to list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I parsed a `.xlsx` file to a `pandas dataframe` and desire converting to a list of tuples. The `pandas dataframe` has two columns.

The list of tuples requires the `product_id` grouped with the `transaction_id`. I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758450/pandas-convert-dataframe-to-array-of-tuples) on creating a `pandas dataframe` to list of tuples, but the code result grouped with `transaction_id` grouped with `product_id.

How can I get the list of tuples in the desired format on the bottom of the page?

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd 
#Import data
trans = pd.ExcelFile('/Users/Transactions.xlsx')
#parse xlsx file into dataframe
transdata = trans.parse('Orders')
#view dataframe
#print transdata

   transaction_id  product_id
0           20001       48165
1           20001       48162
2           20001       48166
3           20004       48815
4           20005       48165

transdata = trans.parse('Orders')
#Create tuple
trans_set = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
print trans_set

[(20001, (48165), (20001, 48162), (20001, 48166), (20004, 48815), (20005, 48165)]

Desired Result:

[(20001, [48165, 48162, 48166]), (20004, 48815), (20005, 48165)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trans_set = [(key,list(grp)) for key, grp in 
             transdata.groupby(['transaction_id'])['product_id']]

In [268]: trans_set
Out[268]: [(20001, [48165, 48162, 48166]), (20004, [48815]), (20005, [48165])]
```

This is a little different than your desired result -- note the `(20004, [48815])`, for example -- but I think it is more consistent. The second item in each tuple is a list of all the `product_ids` which are associate with the `transaction_id`. It might consist of only one element, but it is always a list.

---

To write trans_set to a CSV, you could use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples):

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/data.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key, grp in trans_set:
        writer.writerow([key]+grp)
```

yields a file, `/tmp/data.csv`, with content:

```
20001,48165,48162,48166
20004,48815
20005,48165
```

Comment: Please ask a new question. Show the DataFrame you currently have, and the desired CSV format.

Comment: Sorry @unutbu I am a new python user, was referring to the wrong datatype. Your result gave a list of tuples, how do I save as a .csv?

Comment: What should the CSV look like? For example, should `(20, [1, 2, 3])` become `"20,1,2,3"` or `'20,"[1, 2, 3]"'` or something else?

Comment: I would like "20,1,2,3"

Comment: I checked the .csv output and the values are in different columns, not separated by ",".

Comment: I've posted the result I'm seeing. Is that not what you get? If not, please post data and code which reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I opened the file as a .txt and the results were the same as yours. In my .xlsx file, I had delimiters on.