# Numpy dstack Pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to take 2 pandas dataframe columns and combine them into 1.

Input: 3 Column df `(columns: a , b , num)`

Desired Output: 2 Column df `(columns: (a,b), num)`

Example df:

`a  b  c
 1  2  3
 2  2  8
 2  1  4`

Example output:

`a_b   c
(1,2)  3
(2,2)  8
(2,1)  4`

```
df['a_b'] = np.dstack((df['a'], df['b']))
```

returns an error:

> "Length of values does not match length of index"

Which I have tried to fix but do not fully understand since a, b, and num are all the same length, and the dstack version of a/b should also be that length.

What is going wrong with my approach and what would be the most understandable way to combine these two columns?

Comment: Could you add a small example dataframe so we can see what your data looks like

Comment: @Erfan done, good suggestion!

Comment: `df['a_b'] = list(zip(df.a, df.b))`

Comment: This worked, I will google it to find out how, if you put it in an answer I will accept it, but I see that it is also documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285244/convert-a-dataframe-to-list-of-tuples, should I delete this question?

Comment: No it's a fine question @JoeS