# Equivalent of pandas.Series.unique() for non-hashable elements

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if there is an equivalent for pandas.Series.unique() when the series contains non-hashable elements (in my case, lists).

For instance, with

```py
>> ds
                   XTR
s0b0_VARC-0.200    [0.05, 0.05]
s0b0_VARC-0.100    [0.05, 0.05]
s0b0_VARC0.000     [0.05, 0.05]
s0b0_VARC0.100     [0.05, 0.05]
s0b1_VARC-0.200    [0.05, 0.05]
s0b1_VARC0.000     [0.05, 0.05]
s0b1_VARC0.100     [0.05, 0.05]
s0b2_VARC-0.200    [0.05, 0.05]
s0b2_VARC-0.100    [0.06, 0.025]
s0b2_VARC0.000     [0.05, 0.05]
s0b2_VARC0.100     [0.05, 0.05]
```

I would like to get

```py
>> ds.unique()
2
```

Comment: turn them to tuples?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang)

Inspired from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9762084/11225613), I wrote the following function (not sure how robust it is though):

```py
def count_unique_values(series):
    try:
        tuples = [tuple(x) for x in series.values]
        series = pd.Series(tuples)
        nb = len(series.unique())
        print(nb)
    except TypeError:
        nb = len(series.unique())
    return nb
```