# How to convert Pandas data frame into 2 D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, teradata

I have a Panda data frame

```
    X =

      id                   var1  var2
 0   20000049588638         3    61.62
 1   100798486386           3    61.62
 2   100799238114           3    61.62
```

I want to convert this as a simple 2D array so that I can write this into Teradata database

**Required Output**

```
    X =   
    [(20000049588638,3,61.62),
    (100798486386,3,61.62), 
    (100799238114,3,61.62)]
```

I tried this:

```
    X = X.values.tolist()
```

But, I am getting following output:

```
    [[20000049588638, '3', '61.62'],
    [100798486386, '3', '61.62'],
    [100799238114, '3', '61.62']]
```

Which I am not able to write into the database.

Please check this.

Comment: you can also use: `df.apply(tuple,axis=1).to_numpy()`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9758450/5028532), you can use `itertuples()` and then enclose that in a list.

```
list(X.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Comment: instead of writing the answer I guess you should mark the question as duplicate.

Comment: I had already written the answer before i saw you marking it. Once you did, I upvoted and I also added the link to the question. :)

Comment: Thanks @razdi. But, it's giving me following wrong output: [Pandas(id=20000049588638, var1='3', var2='61.62'),
 Pandas(id=100798486386, var1='3', var2='61.62'),
 Pandas(id=100799238114, var1='3', var2='61.62'),]

Comment: That is cause they are named tuples. I've edited the answer and should give you the ordinary tuples. You should also look at the duplicate question as it has some more insights/answers