# How to convert selected column with index to a list of tuples in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given the dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'Chris', 'Item Purchased': 'Sponge', 'Cost': 22.50},
                   {'Name': 'Kevyn', 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter', 'Cost': 2.50},
                   {'Name': 'Filip', 'Item Purchased': 'Spoon', 'Cost': 5.00}],
                  index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

How do I write a script to produce the following output:

```
[('Store 1', 22.5), ('Store 1', 2.5), ('Store 2', 5.0)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas convert dataframe to array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758450/pandas-convert-dataframe-to-array-of-tuples). There are several solutions that deal with a subset of a dataframe as well.

Comment: You want to sum all the costs for each store, or just transpose the dataframe? (if the data frame has 2 rows with store1, should the output have store1 2 times or just one? I recommend you to be more specific on the transformation you are expecting to perform, because the output can be achieved in many ways.

Answer (score 4):

We can do `zip`

```
list(zip(df.index,df.Cost))
[('Store 1', 22.5), ('Store 1', 2.5), ('Store 2', 5.0)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `items`:

```
list(df['Cost'].items())
#df['Cost'].to_dict().items()
```

---

```
[('Store 1', 22.5), ('Store 1', 2.5), ('Store 2', 5.0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `itertuples` since you have an index set.

```
list(df[['Cost']].itertuples(name=None))
[('Store 1', 22.5), ('Store 1', 2.5), ('Store 2', 5.0)]
```