# Can I transform a Pandas dataframe into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with some correlations in the form of:

```
   A     B  
D  0.78  0.49 
E  0.93  0.67
```

Is there a fast way in Python to get a list of tuples like:
[(A, D, 0.78), (A, E, 0.93), (B, D, 0.49), (B, E, 0.67)]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can. Please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758450/pandas-convert-dataframe-to-array-of-tuples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape, then convert `Series` to `DataFrame` and last convert nested lists to tuples:

```
L = [tuple(x) for x in df.unstack().reset_index().to_numpy()]
```

Or:

```
L = list(map(tuple, df.unstack().reset_index().to_numpy()))
```

Another idea, thank you @Datanovice:

```
L = list(df.unstack().reset_index().itertuples(name=None,index=None))
```

---

```
print (L)
[('A', 'D', 0.78), ('A', 'E', 0.93), ('B', 'D', 0.49), ('B', 'E', 0.67)]
```

If order should be swapped, thank you @Ch3steR:

```
L = list(df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').itertuples(name=None,index=None)) 
print (L)
[('D', 'A', 0.78), ('E', 'A', 0.93), ('D', 'B', 0.49), ('E', 'B', 0.67)]
```

Comment: Another alternative using `df.melt` : `list(df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').itertuples(name=None,index=None))`. Nice answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd
dt = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
cols = ['a', 'b']
rows = ['d', 'e']
df = pd.DataFrame(dt, index=rows)
print(df)

    a   b
d   1   3
e   2   4



result = []
for c in cols:
    for r in rows:
        result.append((c, r, df[c][r]))
print(result)
[('a', 'd', 1), ('a', 'e', 2), ('b', 'd', 3), ('b', 'e', 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible. I would do that like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating example DF
tab = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': (1,2), 'B': (3,4)})
tab.index=['C', 'D']

# Values to tuples
np.array(tab.apply(lambda x: [(x.index[i], x.name,y) for i, y in enumerate(x)])).ravel()
```